# Starting gnome-wayland from xinitrc on 22.10

Tags: gnome, wayland, xinit

I'm starting my system using .xinitrc instead of GDM. My statement for gnome on Xorg is:

```
exec /usr/bin/gnome-session
```

What's the statement to start gnome on wayland?
Thanks.

Comment: Oh, though scratch my prev. comment, doesn't xinit also start xserver? In this case xinit won't work for you, because Wayland compositor is a separate entity that encapsulates XWayland *(a xserver API implementation)*. Although, some Wayland compositors support running inside X-session *(for debugging purposes)*, e.g. Sway can do that. But I doubt you're interested in that mode.

Comment: Dang. That’s something that should have occurred to me. Thanks.